# How to handle low internet connection with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, networking, asihttprequest

I am developing an application which does a lot of API fetching and it happens, if the internet connection is very low, say 5 kbps the app crashes in the `main` method. 
I think it happens when a lot of requests are in the queue so the OS terminates the app.
I am using ASIHTPPRequest and asynchronous block-based requests.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Hi, I've used ASIHTTPRequest before, my comment doesn't really solve your question but if you look at the site again, [link](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) the developer says that he's no longer updating it. So i suggest you try using something else for your fetching of data. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a Single network queue for the whole app. Apps that depend heavily on Internet connectivity should optimize the number of concurrent network operations. Unfortunately, `ASIHTPPRequest` framework does not do this. I would suggest you use `MKNetworkKit` which has been built especially keeping mobile apps in mind.

> Most mobile networks (3G) don’t allow more than two concurrent HTTP
>   connections from a given IP address. Edge is even worse. You can’t, in
>   most cases, open more than one connection. This limit is considerably
>   high (six) on a traditional home broadband (Wifi). On any normal case,
>   the iDevice is mostly connected to a 3G network, which means, you are
>   restricted to upload only two photos in parallel. Now, it is not the
>   slow upload speed that hurts.
>
> The real problem arises when you open a
>   view that loads thumbnails of photos (say on a different view) while
>   this uploading operations are running in the background. When you
>   don’t properly control the queue size across the app, your thumbnail
>   loading operations will just timeout which is not really the right way
>   to do it. The right way to do this is to prioritize your thumbnail
>   loading operation or wait till the upload is complete and the load
>   thumbnails. This requires you to have a single queue across the entire
>   app. MKNetworkKit ensures this automatically by using a single shared
>   queue for every instance of it. While MKNetworkKit is not a singleton
>   by itself, the shared queue is.

[source](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/)

Comment: Poor me, there are 125 calls on ASI in the app. I hope this helps, thank you very much. Although it makes sense to me its a bunch of work now...

Comment: its work making the switch over but its worth it. user experience will improve tremendously. `ASIHttp` is a very stable HTTP library but it was not built with mobile in mind. Since it was in ObjectiveC it naturally leaked into iPhones & iPads. `MKNetworkKit` on the other hand seems to be built ground up with mobile in mind. so we have these queues, netwrok throttling, detect network connection loss, freeze API call incase of no network and auto-retry when it comes back on...

Comment: I switched now totally from ASI to MKNetworkEngine, the performance is now much better but I still have the same problem. How can I cancel the requests form the view?